# Grouping similar records based on one value in xsl 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to group the records based on the value in OperationID tag. If more than one record has same operationId, those records should be present in combinations tag and operationId should be common under operationdetails tag. I am using XSL vesion 1.0. Please find below the input xml and the required xml format. Kindly suggest some solution using 1.0

Input xml :

```
<root>
   <records>
        <record>
             <OperationID>13</OperationID>
             <GroupID>00</GroupID>
             <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
             <ID>123456789</ID>
             <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071249</DocumentID>
             <AllGroupID>JTH</AllGroupID>
             <AllID>B21B1</AllID>
        </record>
        <record>
             <OperationID>13</OperationID>
             <GroupID>00</GroupID>
             <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
             <ID>123456789</ID>
             <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071249</DocumentID>
             <AllGroupID>JTT</AllGroupID>
             <AllID>B21FB</AllID>
        </record>
        <record>
             <OperationID>14</OperationID>
             <GroupID>01</GroupID>
             <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
             <ID>123456788</ID>
             <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071250</DocumentID>
             <AllGroupID>KTH</AllGroupID>
             <AllID>BFFHT</AllID>
        </record>
    </records>
</root>
```

required xml format :

```
<ApplicationArea>
      <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
      <ID>123456789</ID>
   </ApplicationArea>
   <DataArea>
       <OpertionsHeader>
            <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071249</DocumentID>
       </OpertionsHeader>
       <OperationsDetail>
            <OperationID>13</OperationID>
            <GroupID>00</GroupID>
            <Combinations>
               <Allowance>
                     <AllGroupID>JTH</AllGroupID>
                     <AllID>B21B1</AllID>
               </Allowance>
               <Allowance>
                     <AllGroupID>JTT</AllGroupID>
                     <AllID>B21FB</AllID>
               </Allowance>
            </Combinations>
       </OperationsDetail>
       <OperationsDetail>
           <OperationID>14</OperationID>
            <GroupID>01</GroupID>
            <Combinations>
               <Allowance>
                     <AllGroupID>KTH</AllGroupID>
                     <AllID>BFFHT</AllID>
               </Allowance>
            </Combinations>
       </OperationsDetail>
   </DataArea>
```

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Thanks i got it. But it is working only when the file size is small. But my input file size is nearly 8GB and while applying muenchian method it runs for several hours and not getting output.Any alternatives please

Comment: Which processor are you using?

Comment: We are running in shell script which runs on linux machine

Comment: Does that mean you're using libxslt? If you're not sure, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: I am using version 1.0

Comment: That's not what I asked.